# Mathematica cannot find intersection of two functions

Tags: equation-solving, webmathematica

Why mathematica cannot solve this extremely easy equation?
[![My functions][1]][1]
[image]
[image: Plot of three functions]

```
g[x_] := -x + 2
h[x_] := 3 x
f[x_] := -x^2 + 4
```

http: // i.stack.imgur.com/j0wYF.png

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated my question with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions need to be defined before your Solve command.

```
g[x_] := -x + 2;
h[x_] := 3 x;
f[x_] := -x^2 + 4;
Solve[{f[x] == g[x]}, {x}, Reals]
```

Returns

```
{{x -> -1}, {x -> 2}}
```

Comment: I had my functions already defined but I don't know why I got that error. I just copied and pasted what you posted and know it seems to work. Thank you very much.